# Get key combination code of multiple keys

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want to ask you can I get key code combination of multiple keys. For example I can get the key code from this example:

```java
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
    }
}
```

But how I can get the key code of this example:

```java
textField.setText("");
// Process only desired key types
if (event.getCode().isLetterKey()
        || event.getCode().isDigitKey()
        || event.getCode().isFunctionKey()) {
    String shortcut = event.getCode().getName();
    if (event.isAltDown()) {
        shortcut = "Alt + " + shortcut;
    }
    if (event.isControlDown()) {
        shortcut = "Ctrl + " + shortcut;
    }
    if (event.isShiftDown()) {
        shortcut = "Shift + " + shortcut;
    }
    textField.setText(shortcut);
    shortcutKeyEvent = event;
} else {
    shortcutKeyEvent = null;
}
```

Is it possible to get the key code combination of these keys `Ctrl + Tab` or `Ctrl + A`?

Answer (score 21):

No, the handled `keyEvent` has only one main `KeyCode`, for example this code

```
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) { 
    }
}
```

will handle `TAB`, `ALT + TAB`, or `CTRL + TAB` etc. If you only interested in `CTRL + TAB`, you have 2 choices:
1) using isControlDown()

```
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB && event.isControlDown()) { 
    }
}
```

2) using KeyCodeCombination

```
final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.TAB, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
...
...
public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
    if (kb.match(event)) { 
    }
}
```

Comment: Also consider `KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN`. "By using shortcut key modifier, developers can create platform independent shortcuts."

Comment: Problem is because it works also when you only press Tab without Control_Down. How to make Handler which will work only if both keys are pressed ?

Answer (score -1):

I Don't see directly there is any way except Menus 
but still We can handle multi key event e.g. Ctrl + S by below  work around.

at controller class level keep

```
public static boolean halfCtrlSPressed=false;
```

and in Event filter add logic as

```
if(ke.getCode().getName() == "Ctrl") {
            halfCtrlSPressed=true;
        }else if(ke.getCode().getName() == "S"  && halfCtrlSPressed) {
            halfCtrlSPressed=false;
            //doDomething
}
```