# how to comeback to get the first key pressed while another key press happens JAVAFX

Tags: javafx

I need help. I'm working in my scene with an event handler of key presses. and i want to get the f key presses for example, after i press the g key while i'm holding f.

I realized that this cannot happen with a standard event handler. First while i'm holding the f key it handles it, but at the time i press the g key once it handles the g for once and every things stop after.
Thank you,

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getCode().getName());
        }
    });
```

Comment: are you looking for this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002059/get-key-combination-code

Comment: Sorry, no. Yours answers the key combination, which can only work with handling Ctrl, Alt, or Shift + another key, because the way these three works is to wait for another key to enter, therefore they can be used in keyComb, not a case of another key.
I want to hold a normal key (like f) + another one (like g).